# How to use \rightarrow in normal sentence construction

Tags: symbols

I want to use the `\rightarrow` without the `\mathit` command. Here is what I want to write:
`[ID, List of symbols]  \rightarrow  Sequence of rules` but when I write it using `\mathit` command all the spaces are collapsed.

```
(\mathit{[ID, List of symbols]  \rightarrow  Sequence of rules }\)
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Why is it in math mode in the first place?

Comment: Use text or textit (or a combination of both) (and also what Werner said???)

Comment: I get a "! Missing $ inserted" error

Comment: @bruce: Use `[ID, List of symbols] $\rightarrow$ Sequence of rules`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the text parts of your formula text instead of maths

`$\hbox{[ID, List of symbols]}  \rightarrow  \hbox{Sequence of rules}$`

or if you prefer "proper" LaTeX and you have the amsmath package loaded to give you the `\text` command

`\(\text{[ID, List of symbols]} \rightarrow \text{Sequence of rules}\)`

[image]